# What is the proper position of "gern"?

Tags: adverb, word-order

For example, which of these is correct:

> Ich esse gern Pizza

or

> Ich esse Pizza gern

Comment: There is even a third alternative: *Gerne esse ich Pizza.* although it might not be all that elegant... But grammatically it's correct.

Comment: You can also say: "Pizza esse ich gern."

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both are correct. To me, *Ich esse gerne Pizza* hints at a question like *Was ist Dein Lieblingsessen*, whereas *Ich esse Pizza gern* would be more appropriate as an answer to *Magst Du Pizza?* That is, I would put the important word (the one carrying new information) at the end of the phrase.

Comment: +1 , I'd like to add that the second alternative "Ich esse Pizza gern." is also a good response if another person just said that he or she doesn't like pizza. "Ich esse Pizza gern." then has a notion of "I don't get how one can't like it" whereas "Ich esse gern Pizza" would be a bit more doubtful as to whether you yourself are a bit weird for liking it... it is veeeeeeery subtle though, my subjective perception and it highly depends on intonation I guess

Answer (score 12):

*Ich esse gern Pizza* sounds more natural than *Ich esse Pizza gern* to a native speaker, even though both are correct.

Better: Ich esse gerne Pizza (standard language)

Answer (score 7):

It depends. When you want to express that pizza is your favourite meal you can say:

> Ich esse gern Pizza.

When you admit that you would be happy to eat pizza, e.g. that has already been ordered or served, you would say:

> Ich esse Pizza gern.

In the first case, I would prefer "gerne" instead of "gern".

Answer (score 4):

You can also say

> *"Ich mag Pizza"* - this means that you like pizza.

*"Ich esse Pizza gern"* is a more formal way of saying it but if you want to say it to friends you should just say *"ich mag Pizza"* - they all mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The "proper position" depends of emphasis:

1) Ich esse gerne Pizza means I like *pizza.* (As opposed to hamburgers or frankfurters.)

2) Ich esse Pizza *gern* means "I *like* pizza." (As opposed to hate it.)

In either case, the part to be emphasized is at the end of the sentence.

Between the above, 1) is considered a bit more "standard" than 2)