# Position of “gern”

Tags: grammar, difference, word-order

Is there a difference between the placement of *gern* after the verb and at the end of the sentence? I‘ve seen it done both ways and semantically, it is the same.

*Examples*

> Ich schwimme **gern** im Meer.
>
> Ich spiele meine Gitarre **gern**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper position of “gern”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4110/9551) or [“gern” and “nicht gern” position](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23561/9551)

Comment: I feel the urge to close the first question linked as a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be sure to do it correct, put it after the finite verb, because there are sentences where you can't put *gern* at the end, like:

> Ich gehe gern schwimmen

But in sentences with only one verb, both ways are possible. But *gern* at the end doesn't sound very natural in most cases.

Comment: I think you wanted to say "put it after the finite verb". "Schwimmen" is still a verb ;) The second sentence then should start with "In sentences with only a finite verb". But then also be careful. A sentence can consist of a subject and verb only, e.g. "Ich schwimme". When keeping the word order, "both ways" (after the verb and at the end of the sentence) result in the very same sentence, "Ich schwimme gern".